# Cross-domain tracking: Track if users actually cross domains

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager, userid

Pls apologize if I'm not clear enough, i'll try to be as concise as possible.

I'm working on a a company that created it's own competitors, each has it own website, all share the same GA through GTM. Cross-domain tracking is implemented and working.

I want to know if users do actually visit these different sites, which is very likely because there is a lot of research before buying what this company offers.

I understand User Id's will not do the trick because I want to track them before visitors identify themselves through a form. There's no login.

Initially I thought I'll be able to create a segment to narrow down to users with more than one of this company's domains in their history, but that is not working. Should that do the trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the view that get all data you have to create a segment to show users that visited first and second domain. If it is greater than 0 means the cross domain is set correctly.

For good implementation see Troubleshooting Cross-Domain Tracking in Google Analytics: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.simoahava.com/amp/analytics/troubleshooting-cross-domain-tracking-in-google-analytics/

Comment: Did that and got zero, so I've reviewed the configuration and noticed two missing parameters on gtm: the allowLinker field, and cookie domains was set to auto instead of each domain. Also added each domain as referral exclusion. So I'll give it a few days and try again.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, let me know. Also, if the answer has been helpful in analyzing your problem, mark it as such. Thank you.

Comment: It's not working. I've created a segment to filter users that include hostname A and hostname B, and got 0 users. I don't see how else could I filter it. Any Thoughts?
I've also created a custom dimension at user level to record hostnames, then created a segment to filter by such custom dimension and still nothing. Guess that won't work as cross-domain apparently is not working.
I'm not user what to do now.
Recap: Two Sites, different hostnames, one GTM with one GA account. Said GTM's GA variable has cookie domain as 'auto', allowLinker as 'true', and both domains added as auto link.
TY.

Comment: Hi Michele. Thanks again for your answer. Guess cross-domain tracking is not what I'm looking for.
I want to know if the visitors for domain A and domain B are the same. But the traffic will almost always be from paid search, there is no link from one domain to the other, as Simo Ahava explains.

Comment: This is not possible, as there are two different users for Google Analytics. If you have a login area you can trace the User-ID (when the user logs in) otherwise you have no way to distinguish them unless you somehow manage to associate a cookie with the user and then rely on that but whatever it is you need a system outside of Google Anaytics.